# Can someone please explain the logic behind using space in function call to an int value?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I am doing this

```
>>> 5.bit_length()
```

I am getting SyntaxError: invalid syntax

but runs fine when using space

```
>>> 5 .bit_length()
 Result -> 3
```

How does it reads the space ?

Comment: >>> a = 5
>>> a.bit_length()
3
This works, unclear about your use case of why a space is needed.

Comment: You can always add extra spaces between an expression and the `.` attribute access, e.g. `'asdssds'    .lower()   .upper()` the spaces are basically ignored. However, in the specific case of *numeric* literals, there is an ambiguity, because `5.` is a valid floating point literal, so `5.whatever` becomes a syntax error, because it's being parsed as float literal. A space suffices for this, hence `5 .whatever` is valid syntax, although a TypeError, but `5.whatever` is invalid syntax. More typically, you'd see parentheses, so `(5).bit_length()`

Comment: @AviThaker yes, but `5.bit_length()` is a syntax error.

Comment: Got the answer ! Thanks